# Extract IPs before string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cut

I have this text:

```
111.11.1.111(*)222.22.2.221(mgn)333.33.3.333(srv)
111.11.1.111(*)333.33.3.333(srv)222.22.2.222(mgn)
222.22.2.223(mgn)111.11.1.111(*)333.33.3.333(srv)
```

I only want to know the IP's before (mgn), output:

```
222.22.2.221
222.22.2.222
222.22.2.223
```

thanks

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through grep,

```
$ grep -oP '(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?=\(mgn\))' file
222.22.2.221
222.22.2.222
222.22.2.223
```

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/.*\b\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\)(mgn).*/\1/g' file
222.22.2.221
222.22.2.222
222.22.2.223
```